# Replace diode in Panasonic fridge

Tags: diodes

Our Panasonic side-by-side fridge stopped working completely. No lights, no display, no nothing. I opened up the control board and one of the diodes was burned. As it turns out, this seems to be a common problem that in Panasonic fridges of this kind the diode D202 is overheating.

[image]

The label on the diode says **AR S1 41** but I couldn't find any datasheet of it.

**Question:** Can someone help me to find a good/better replacement diode or give the specs?

**Edit:** Since ElectronicsStudent gave such an elaborated answer, I'd like to give some more details. I tried searching the web but couldn't find a real data sheet. Here is what I have: The label on the board reads:

- B53V2
- BG-193780
- S40415

All my web-searches for that only brought me to pages where I can buy replacement parts for the fridge but no further information about the board.

Also, I made a big picture of the whole board with a small red arrow where the diode was

[image]

Here is a picture of the diode together with a 1N4007 that came with my Arduino box.

[image]

Comment: Please see my response. I did edit it. Have fun!

Comment: Looking at the picture of the desoldered diode, it looks like you lifted the inner plating and pad ring from one of the holes. This will require care and possibly extra work when soldering in a replacement. Check carefully what copper the diode is supposed to connect to, both on the top and bottom layers of the board (and pray there were no inner layers with connections).

Comment: @marcelm Yep, you are right. The element was so burned/corroded to the board that even after using desoldering braid carefully, the diode didn't move a bit and parts of the plating stuck to it. Luckily, both layers in this region are pretty empty and I have lots of space to create a good connection. If push comes to shove, I can even use two small wires. When the bigger diodes arrive, I'll try to make it beautiful .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that easy to answer as you did not provide the required information.

**How I interpret the picture you provided:**
This is a diode used in the rectifier section of your board. It has to deal with mains voltages and was not suitable for the load.

**What my approach is:**
Get a Diode that is 400V VBr or higher within a bigger package. This way it won't get that hot. A lot of assumptions here, but you may be lucky. Here is a link to a datasheet. https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds29003.pdf
Check the physical dimensions to make sure you 'pimp-up' your current diode.
And again: Make sure to use the correct voltage rating ('Well above' does no harm).

**What my advice is:**
At first you should gather more information. Search the web for information. What device is used? How did others solve this problem? What kind of replacements were reported to work just fine? Is there a partlist (You could get lucky with Panasonic)? Is a schematic available? Or a block diagram? **If you find information you are welcome to come back to me!**
After this start fixing it.
If you have a common sense and some 'electronics-knowledge' try my approach. If not, do not deal with mains stuff. You can hurt or severely injure yourself! Seek help in a local electronics repair shop - yes, they do still exist.

**Strong disclaimer:**
All my advice is based on assumptions. Make sure you are in fact dealing with a standard rectifier diode. If it is a different type or serves a different purpose in your device, replacing it can damage your circuit permanently. Also the device you are replacing could be part of a safety related design block. The block could be rendered useless by using a device with false specs.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
After additional Information was provided I need to change my assumptions. The diode seems to be part of a switch mode supply arrangement. You will be fine with a bulk standard rectifier diode in my opinion. May I suggest: Try your 1n4007 and test the device. If it works you can be sure that a rectifier diode was required. But make sure to order a 'bigger' one to deal with the overheating. See 1n5408 or similar sizing.

**Edit-Edit:**
The way the contact looks on the PCB you may be in trouble. Check if this is a two-layer board. If not, make sure there a no connections to the diode on the inner layers. (Flashlight from the backside and tricks like that) Also, while soldering  you could 'rub' off some of the solder mask around the holes above the tracks to get a good contact as the via seems to be messed up. And high resistance can cause intense heat, which can harm the PCB!

Comment: Thanks for this long answer. I updated my answer with a large image of the full board. The only schematic I could find was one that purpose of the connections of the board. On another board, someone said they used a 1N400X as a replacement, but it looks smaller than the one that was on there (see image). And my thought was that in that case size does matter and it would definitely overheat faster. Maybe you have another comment with a picture of the whole board available?

Comment: Just saw your edit. Thanks a lot. I will give the 1n4007 a try and then follow your other suggestion. Again, thanks a lot, it's much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome sir!

Comment: [It seems you saved the Saturday!](https://imgur.com/IiYc9OH)

Comment: https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/028/021/work.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with a 1N4004 rectifier diode